# Looking for an icon without knowing the size

Tags: icons, gtk, size, gtk3

I'm trying to call gtk_icon_theme_lookup_icon() but problem is that the size of the icon is not known at this time.

Is it possible to call this function with something like "size = -1;"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; from the [documentation of `gtk_icon_info_load_icon()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkIconTheme.html#gtk-icon-info-load-icon):

> Renders an icon previously looked up in an icon theme using `gtk_icon_theme_lookup_icon()`; the size will be based on the size passed to `gtk_icon_theme_lookup_icon()`.

So, you'll have to look up the icon later when you know the size; perhaps just before you render it into a pixbuf.